# Can I connect an adjective with a noun using "and"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, coordinating-conjunctions

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

"Gandalf is a wizard and brave"

Each of "Gandalf is a wizard" and "Gandalf is brave" sound OK, but connecting the noun and adjective descriptions of Galndalf with the "and" hurts my ear. I am not a native English speaker though, and unsure whether connections like that are acceptable in English.

Comment: Needs a comma: _Gandalf is a wizard, and brave._

Comment: You might just want to say _Gandalf is a brave wizard_ if this is only for informational purposes. To say _Gandalf is a wizard, and brave_ will either express that calling him brave was an afterthought by the speaker, or give it that archaic flair that is expected when talking about Gandalf.

Comment: Your ear is right: that's not normal English. You can use it deliberately for effect (in the same way that you can use garden path sentences intentionally for effect), but don't use it in normal speech or you'll sound odd.

Comment: Don't use [Yoda](http://www.yodaquotes.net/) as a guide to English. :-)

Comment: I mostly agree with the others. But I think *Gandalf is brave and a wizard* is slightly better. I'd have to think about why.

Comment: The _and_ appears to draw a parallel where none exists: I like the Summer and the city.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, your example sounds perfectly fine to me: I'm curious about grammar, about semantics, not about artistic expression. For that purpose your example "I like <noun> and <noun>" is indistinguishable from "I like meat and potatoes".

Comment: @Cerberus: your example is "Gendalf is <adjective> and a <noun>" has almost the same ring in my ear as mine "Gendalf is a <noun> and <adjective>". I was wondering whether it's semantically connect nouns and adjective to the same object via "and".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Michael, I am taking you at your word that you see no problem with Summer and the city. I mean no disrespect. As a child, I discovered that everyone called a very reddish orange a 'bright red,' and I decided I could still see it as orange and label it red, too. Most people will not find a parallel between Summer and city, or wizard and brave. That is the garden path sentence referred to above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this - it's called a hendiadys and is most often used for poetic effect.

> **hendiadys** *noun*
>   The expression of a single idea by two words connected with ‘and’, e.g. nice and warm, when one could be used to modify the other, as in nicely warm.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hendiadys)

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Stack Exchange encourages answers to be objectively correct. Links to authoritative works accompanied by appropriate quotations can help (e.g. the dictionary entry I edited into your answer), as can logical argument etc. Thanks for visiting and contributing an answer.